Educational Cartoon children show about whole numbers and fractions
I saw this show in 1997. Educational cartoon about fractions and whole number.
Not sure if it was a show or a one time lengthy episode. This was the only episode I saw.
The story begins by telling the audience about a village in which only whole numbers live. Number 3 for example always does thing three times. Number 4 lives with number 7 ... Etc.. Not sure about what each number does.
One day they wake up and discover something is missing (maybe two slices of pizza or a third of a pie) and they call the police man of the village (he is number 76 or 766 (can't remember)) and he investigates the incident. He asks some numbers about it and they all deny because none of them is capable of eating fractions of the pie/pizza. They would all eat the whole thing or multiples of the whole thing depending on what number they represent.
And then they discover someone new in the village.. He is the fraction 4/6 and at first they are shocked to see him because he looks odd and some consider it a dis figuration "in the universe of whole numbers". So the police man accuses him of the crime. But the fraction explains that he is innocent because he is 4/6 which means he would have to eat 4 out of 6 pieces of the pizza. 
The fraction helps the villagers understand what fractions are and at the end guides numbers into transforming into a fraction ( example: number 2 becomes 4/2 and number 3 becomes 9/3 ,, etc)
They all thank him and he leaves. Then the police man discovers that he WAS INDEED the one who is to be blames since he HIMSELF was disguising ( he showed up as 4/6 but he is really nothing more than 2/3 ) which was the missing part of the pizza/pie.
The last scene shows the policeman promising to keep looking for the fraction, but he is not as smart as 2/3 because he hides in plain sight by transforming himself into fractions like 6/9)
Has anyone else seen this?

wow, that sure is one heck of a way to teach fractions to kids.

Well, I found it, but I'm not sure what it's from. It's possibly just a short educational cartoon. Anyway, here it is - it's called The Weird Number and you've described its plot well (only the sheriff is 763 and the stolen item is a piece of bread):




Thank you so much. I found out that it is part of (Exploring Mathematics) series. How did you come up with it?

Nothing fancy really, I just searched for a cartoon about natural numbers.
